# Multiple screen sizes and XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have read everything I can find, and I just can't figure this out.  I have an XML with a heading, then a listview, and then 2 buttons on the bottom row.  In order to make the layout look perfect, I have "hardcoded" the size (467dp) of the listview.  This is fine on my Samsung Galaxy S4, but I'm not sure it will look appropriate on other phones of slightly different sizes.  I tested it on a Galaxy 8" tab and it did not look right.  I then tested it on a 10.1" tab and it (again) did not look right.  Basically the bottom buttons were up in the middle of the screen.  I got around this by creating layouts for sw600dp and sw720dp.  For each of those I had to hardcode a different size for the listview.  It would seem to me that there is a better way to have a heading-listview-button XML that would display (relatively) the same on any device.  Can anyone please tell me how to to alter my XML so I don't have to hardcode the size of the listview?

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/workout_locations">
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/location_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="467dp"
    android:longClickable="true" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/help_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/help_description"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_description"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this might help:

ensure that the entire layout is a relativeLayout, and inside it, put the listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/location_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" // the size of the buttons height
    android:longClickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

and below it another relativelayout with the buttons inside it.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/help_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/help_description"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_description"
    />
```

If this still causes an issue, then you could write :

```
android:layout_above="@+id/relButtonLayout"
```

inside the listview.

Comment: This one worked for me.  I put everything in a relative layout (didn't need multiple relative layouts), set the last listview (the one with buttons) to "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and everything worked out great.  I did the same to every other XML file in my project and it looks great.  Thanks!

Comment: Very glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

android:layout_weight="1   add this in the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_weight to take up as much room that can be afforded.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/location_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    android:longClickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: See below, this does not work because the buttons scroll up towards the top of the screen. I need them to stay at the very bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you've hardcoded some sizes, you can bet it won't look good in most of the devices. In order to do that, it's always better using `layout_height` and `layout_weight` set to `wrap_content` or `match_parent` depending on what you need.

There's another important tool for the case you describe: `layout_weight`, as you might have already used. Messing with a `ListView` to fit the design you want can be hard at the first time, but once you discover how to set up its layout it's easy for the rest of them.

In my case, this definition always work as should:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylistview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Take a look at it: I've set a singular `LinearLayout` (in this case because it has more views than just the `ListView` I'm showing), but I'm setting the weight of that `ListView` to 1, being the `sumWeights` of that `LinearLayout` 1. This way you assure yourself the `ListView` will expand as long as it can, without the needing of hardcoding values.

It's just a matter of playing around with it for a while, but the less values you hardcode, the more adaptable will be on other devices.

Comment: I tried this already.  The problem is that the buttons need to stay on the bottom.  When you define the ListView as 0dp then the buttons scroll up towards the top of the screen.  I need them to stay at the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: Then simply add your buttons within another `RelativeLayout` with the `orientation` property set to `horizontal` just below the `LinearLayout` that contents your `ListView` and set its `layout_alignParentBottom` to `true`.